# How do I prevent anacron from running certain scripts?

Tags: linux, raid, cron, mdadm

I am running RHEL5 and software RAID (mdadm). Currently I allow the 99-raid-check weekly cron script to run at the normal time (early Sunday morning). However, if the system is off during that time it will run when the system boots with a delay. Looking at the man page for anacrontab and /etc/anacrontab, I can see the current config is set to run every 7 days with a delay of 70 minutes for the cron.weekly scripts. I need to be able to predict when there will be high disk IO, so I want it to run early Sunday morning if it's on, or not at all. My question is, how can I prevent 99-raid-check just to wait until the following week to run and not utilize anacron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option would be to modify your script to check for I/O load and only run if it is below a threshold. Use something like [`iostat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat) and add a check in your script that will only run if I/O is below X. You can then leave the `cron` as is since the script itself will deal with checking the load.

Comment: thank you for your comment.  However this would not fulfill my needs.  The IO will spike when mdadm rebuilds the arrays, which is fine, but I want to be able to control the hours that it occurs.

Comment: @user2789281 if all you want tis for it to run Sunday morning or not at all, just use a normal `crontab` and give it a specific time.

Comment: yes, I think that's exactly what I will do since anacrontab doesn't read crontab.  Thanks.